# Weird Export of .M4A format

Tags: bugs, export, import, sound

When Exporting .M4A format audio, the duration is always 1. It seems that the audio is fast-forward played...

Is that a bug and how can I fix it?

Sample code:

```
ImportString[ExportString[
    Audio@Play[Sin[(400 + 400 t) t] + Sin[(430 + 400 t) t], {t, 0, 10}],
"M4A"], "M4A"]
```

The duration of the output audio is 1 second:

```
Duration@%
```

> 1.02166s

Comment: What version are you running?  I'm running 11.2 and this plays for 10 seconds as expected.

Comment: On `MMA 11.3` gives: `1.02166s`.Probably a bug!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the same problem with version: 11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)

The documentation for [M4A](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/M4A.html) says that MMA follows the ISO/IEC 13818-7 standard and that "a few sampling frequencies from 8kHz to 96kHz" are supported.

The standard lists these sample rates:

```
isoiec13818rates = {8000, 11025, 12000, 16000, 22050, 24000, 32000, 
   44100, 48000, 64000, 88200, 96000};
```

However, only two of the frequencies, 44100 and 48000, result in a correct 10-second sound. Whenever the export and import frequencies don't match, the sound is wrong.

```
TableForm[{#, 
    SampleRate /. 
     Options[ImportString[
       ExportString[
        Audio[Play[
          Sin[(400 + 400 t) t] + Sin[(430 + 400 t) t], {t, 0, 10}], 
         SampleRate -> #], "M4A"]], SampleRate]} &/@ 
  isoiec13818rates, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"export kHz", "import kHz"}}]
```

```
export kHz  import kHz
8000        44100
11025       44100
12000       44100
16000       44100
22050       44100
24000       44100
32000       44100
44100       44100
48000       48000
64000       48000
88200       48000
96000       48000
```

So `SampleRate -> 44100` or `SampleRate -> 48000` "fixes" the problem.

```
ImportString[
 ExportString[
  Audio[Play[Sin[(400 + 400 t) t] + Sin[(430 + 400 t) t], {t, 0, 10}],
    SampleRate -> 44100], "M4A"]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved my problem!

Comment: You're welcome. I think the problem is a bug, or Wolfram's current version of M4A doesn't fully implement the ISO/IEC 13818-7 standard.